# Jar is not running completely while invoking from a batchfile

Tags: java, jar, batch-processing

I have batch file which invokes a . The main class of that jar is invoked properly and I have given `system.out.println` in every line but it is executing only up to first three sysouts and stopping. No errors or exceptions.

Following is the sample of my batch file code:

```
CD D:\DT_Commercebnk_dblByte_merger\V001\DMP_HOME\Parser_Kit_Jan_2013\Parser\BIN

echo "parser called"

set PGMLIST=../XREF/inputList.txt

SET CLASSPATH=%classpath%;..\\LIB\\GenericParser.jar;
echo %CLASSPATH%

cd..\\LIB

@REM del /Q ..\LOG.txt

@REM programName.DDS DDS INTERMEDIATE N ApplicationName

for /f %%a in (%PGMLIST%) do (
java main.Main %%a ORACLE INTERMEDIATE N TEST N
echo %%a
)
cd ..
cd Bin
```

Comment: You should add a sample of your code..

Comment: Add your **Java** code.